# Java Login with main and setVisible not working

Tags: java

I tried this code where in a text file I need 4 login usernames and passes, but when I did the main to try, setVisible is not working NetBeans says that find the setVisible symbol and when I delete to run, it only builds and nothing pops up.Here's the code hoping that someone can help me thanks

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner; // I use scanner because it's command line.

public class Identification {

     public void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TP3\\Accessinit.txt"));
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user = scan.nextLine();
        String pass = scan.nextLine(); // looks at selected file in scan
        String inpUser = keyboard.nextLine();
        String inpPass = keyboard.nextLine(); // gets input from user
        if (inpUser.equals(user) && inpPass.equals(pass)) {
            System.out.print("login");
        } else {
            System.out.print("error");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Identification idento = new Identification();
        idento.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see visible variable or setVisible method defined in your Identification class so it is impossible to invoke it. You can try something like this if this suits you

```
public class Identification {
    private boolean visible;

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
         this.visible = visible;
    }

public void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TP3\\Access\\init.txt"));
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String user = scan.nextLine();
    String pass = scan.nextLine(); // looks at selected file in scan

    String inpUser = keyboard.nextLine();
    String inpPass = keyboard.nextLine(); // gets input from user

    if (inpUser.equals(user) && inpPass.equals(pass)) {
        System.out.print("login");
    } else {
        System.out.print("error");
    }

}
```